# Access 2016 linked table to another access database not updateable

Tags: ms-access

I have created a local user interface that uses a number of linked tables from a shared access database on a network server.  When I try and add/modify records from the UI to the linked tables on the server (from a form) I get the "Operation must use an updateable query."  error message.

Problem solving so far:

1. Checked to make sure I had read/write/create access to the shared network folder.
2. Ensured that the tables in question were indexed with a primary key.
3. Opened the shared network database directly and added/edited records from the same computer that I am testing the UI on (in other words simply reconfirming the access noted under point 1).
4. Added the local and shared folders to the databases trusted locations.

I have worked with Access for years and never stumbled across this situation previously.

Further information - UI is installed on a Win 10 machine and the shared db is on a Win 7 machine.

Comment: *a local user interface* - is this in Access? If yes, what happens if you try to edit in the linked tables directly?

Comment: See my OP.  Was able to edit the linked tables directly.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted the issue out.  Seems it was a Windows security issue with a particular folder on the network server.  Created a new shared folder with new permissions, copied the shared database, updated the table links and all work fine now.